# How to get exact speed using location manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

My map app records the details of current location from newLocation. But speed when is returned by the newLocation.speed is not exact as what my bike's speed-o-meter. When its 60 on my bike speed-o-meter the newLocation.speed shows 18. Please help me to find the exact speed.

Comment: Are you sure you're comparing the same units of measurement?

Comment: Also, given the variability in the GPS calculation, grabbing the speed solely from the last location record is unlikely to be terribly accurate. I'd be inclined to look at the last few location records and doing some trailing average. This should smooth the results a little, yielding something closer to a real speed.

Comment: You'd be far better off doing a little math and calculating it with the accelerometer.

Comment: ya am sure that am comparing same units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted it out myself. There was an error in conversion from m/s to KMPH and MPH.

Comment: Hello Manoj, can you help me out in this? I have also same problem. The speed i am getting is not at all accurate!! Looking forward to your response.

Comment: The value which we get from newLocation.speed or oldLocation.speed is in meters/sec. So we can convert it to as per our need.

Comment: To convert it to KMPH just multiply newLocation.speed * 3.6

Comment: How can i get accurate speed in KM/Hour?

Comment: as I said just get the value from newLocation.speed and multiply it with 3.6 you get the readings now in KM/Hour.

Comment: This is not accurate, I have tested it.

Comment: Some times it is coming -3.6?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28366/discussion-between-nikhil-bansal-and-manoj)

Answer (score 1):

The unit of newLocation.speed is m/s (meters per second) . Check if the mesurement units of the newLocation.speed and your bike's speed-o-meter are the same

Comment: Thanks for your reply petros. I have already sorted out this issue. Thanks again for your time to help me.